# angular's $scope not updating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a basic weather app based on the user's location, which I take using javascript geolocation service. Everything regarding the location and weather works as expected.
My problem is when the user reject the location request, what I want to do is hide the weather data (which I can't get) and show an appropriate message.
**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="weatherApp">
  <div class="container text-center" style="margin-top: 15vh" ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
    <h1>Local Weather App</h1>
    <h3>{{error}}</h3>
    <div class="row" ng-hide="showError">
      <div id="loc-col" class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
        <h3>{{data.name}}</br>
        <small>{{data.sys.country}}</small></h3>
      </div>
      <div id="temp-col" class="col-xs-4">
        <h3>{{data.main.temp}} {{degree}}&deg;</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="weather-col" class="col-xs-3">
        <h3>{{data.weather[0].main}} </br><small>{{data.weather[0].description}}</small> </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="icon-col" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <img id="icon" class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{icon}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The error message should be in the `<h3>` below the h1.

**JS:**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('weatherApp', []);

app.factory('weatherFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  var weather = {};

  weather.getWeather = function(lat, lon){
    return $http.jsonp("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&units=metric&callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
  };
  return weather;
}]);

app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope', 'weatherFactory', '$http', function($scope, weatherFactory, $http){
  $scope.degree = "C";

  $scope.error = "";
  $scope.showError = false;

  var icons = { };

  function getWeatherFromPos(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    weatherFactory.getWeather(lat,lon).success(
            function(data){
              $scope.data = data;
              $scope.icon = icons[data.weather[0].icon];
            }
          ).error(function(error){
            setError(error);
          });
  }

  function setError(error){
    $scope.showError = true;
    $scope.error = error;
  }

  //THIS IS THE RELEVANT CODE:
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
          getWeatherFromPos(position);
        }, 
        function() {
          //EXECUTED UPON REJECTION
          setError("Geolocation service failed.");
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      setError("Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
    }
}]);
```

When I open up the consoler and I execute the following:

```
angular.element($(".row")).scope().error
"Geolocation service failed."
```

So somehow the variable do get updated, but the error message is not shown and the weather data is not hidden.

Comment: `angular.element($(".row"))` is a collection of elements unless there is only one with that class.

Comment: @charlietfl as you see in the html code, there is only one element with that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setError` function execute out of `$digest` cycle of angular.
You can do follow:

```
  function setError(error){
    $scope.showError = true;
    $scope.error = error;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
```

or

```
function setError(error){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
       $scope.showError = true;
       $scope.error = error;
   }
}
```

P.S.: It is concerned about `setError("Geolocation service failed.");` and `setError("Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");`.

But for `setError(error)` it is not ok to use `$apply` because it is already inside `$digest` loop (there is no need to call `$apply` method). Remember you need to call `$apply` only after you made some changes outside of angular digest loop. See more about it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: Thank you, any chance you can explain why said expressions are outside the `$digest` loop and how can I identify and prevent that?

Comment: Implement all your function as `$scope` methods, and all your code will be executed inside `$digest loop`. For example: `$scope.setError = ...` and you will be able to call it as `$scope.setError(...)`

Comment: Adding $scope doesn't work, using $apply like you said in the answer helped, though so thanks.

Comment: I'd still like to know how can I know how can I know which function is executed within the $digest loop.
Why there was only a problem with the setError() function but not with the getWeatherFromPos()?

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` execute asynchronously, so angular dont know what happening after it is finished (we need to call `$scope.$apply()` to tell about it). `getWeatherFromPos` uses `getWeather` method which returns `$http`. `$http` has two methods `success` and `error` which is already executed inside `$digest` loop. So there is no need to call `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 0):

I think thank you missed ng-bind:

```
<h3 ng-bind="error">{{error}}</h3>
```

Comment: `ng-bind="error"` and `{{error}}` do the same thing

Comment: I seen in my own project that it will make difference

Comment: difference in what? it is redundant to use them together. Read the docs...they say the same thing I am saying: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: That's not what it says...it says scope is not updating

Comment: it was the same - it was {{arg}}, update from scope - no result.
After adding ng-bind it worked.

Comment: Read the docs...it even says most common is use `{{}}` instead of `ng-bind`. Whatever issue you solved was not related. `ng-bind` replaces content in that element also...so using both makes no sense